# How to distinguish class LineSegment from Line?

Tags: c++, class

I use two `Point`s to define a `Line` and also a `LineSegment`, like:

```
class Point { ... };
class Line
{
  Point p1, p2;
  //...
};
class LineSegment
{
  Point p1, p2;
  //...
};
```

`LineSegment` has the same definition as `Line`, so I used `typedef Line LineSegment` at first instead of defining another `LineSegment` class. But soon, I found I couldn't define the function `distance` to calculate the distance between a point and a line or a point and a line segment.

```
class Point { ... };
class Line
{
  Point p1, p2;
  //...
};
typedef Line LineSegment;
double distance(const Point& a, const Line& b) { ... }
double distance(const Point& a, const LineSegment& b) { ... }
```

Certainly I will get a compile error.

So, my question is: **Is there a better way to distinguish `Line` from `LineSegment` without redefine `LineSegment`**?

Comment: Define `AbstractLine` having two points, then subclass into `Line` and `LineSegment`?

Comment: Instead of using two `Point`s for `Line`, you could use a value for gradient and another one for y-intercept (assuming you are in 2D).

Comment: If they're the same, don't differentiate between them. Only have one definition, and therefore one function. Don't repeat yourself. If their functionality diverges later, then Amadan's solution is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I follow *@Amadan*'s suggestion. Create a abstract class.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point { int x, y; };
struct AbstractLine { Point p1, p2; };
struct Line : AbstractLine { };
struct LineSegment : AbstractLine { };

void distance(const Point& a, const Line& b)
{
  std::cout << "void distance(const Point& a, const Line& b)" << std::endl;
}
void distance(const Point& a, const LineSegment& b)
{
  std::cout << "void distance(const Point& a, const LineSegment& b)" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
  Point p;
  Line a;
  LineSegment b;
  distance(p, a);
  distance(p, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A line segment has a start point and an end point, whereas a line may be uniquely defined by only the point on it closest to the origin (or some other representation).

So the Line representation is either invalid or excessive.

**Edit:** Aha, I knew I was missing something! If you use the point on the line closest to the origin (x, y), then the slope is (–x/y), and a second point on the line can easily be constructed at (x+y, y–x). So the implementation of Line can compute that to delegate operations to LineSegment using a temporary object, at less expense than loading additional values from memory. (The temporary should live entirely in registers.)

```
class LineSegment {
    std::array< Point, 2 > terminus;
public:
    double angle() { return ... }
};

class Line {
    Point nearest_origin;

    LineSegment toLineSegment() {
        return {
            nearest_origin,
            { nearest_origin[0] + nearest_origin[1],
              nearest_origin[1] - nearest_origin[0] }
        };
    }
public:
    double angle()
        { return toLineSegment().angle(); }
};
```

(Ugh… now that I wrote all that I can see that actually you want delegation to go the other way here, and subtract the coordinates of LineSegment to produce a Line at the correct angle. Anyway, this works and you get the point. Such delegation can go both ways, whereas inheritance is usually a one-way street.)

---

Moreover, you shouldn't `typedef` things just because the data members inside are similar. Why not just typedef them both to arrays? A class represents a distinct concept.

I recommend against the AbstractLine suggestion, unless there are meaningful methods to put in there. Start from the interface and fill in the internal details in the most convenient way. Classes shouldn't share implementation just because they look the same, but because the implementations are doing conceptually the same thing.

Because math is tricky, math classes should be written to allow changing internal representations, and public inheritance is a bit dangerous. Because math doesn't involve "actors" and actions, but rather generic operations with properties like commutativity, OOP is often a poor fit in general.

Comment: I think use points to define a line is convenient, because I use vector *dot product* and *cross product* to do calculation. And if I use a abstract class, these two class could share many functions, for example, `get_slope`, or, what ever...

Comment: @abcdabcd987 Then, use inheritance. But use `private` or `protected` inheritance, and `using` declarations to expose the interface, so the user doesn't rely on internal deatails that you wouldn't want to guarantee forever.

Comment: If you think about semantics, and unless the usage suggests otherwise (as it seems to in this case), you are of course correct: it makes more sense to define a (2D) line as a direction and offset. I was simply addressing the question "why this doesn't work" on abstract OOP basis: a typedef'd type is not a different type, and can't distinguish a signature, and subclassing makes them distinct while still sharing functionality.

Comment: @Amadan In terms of OOP, you're right, but math isn't necessarily amenable to OOP. See my edit… there's actually a simple implementation where `Line` can create a temporary `LineSegment` object to handle common operations, which is more efficient in every way, but doesn't allow inheritance.